# Convert an array in another specific array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do an exercise and I need to convert this an array in another specific array, but unfortunately, I couldn't.

I need to convert this array:

```
    let data = [
    [
      "2020-01-28",
      100
    ],
    [
      "2020-01-27",
      80
    ],
    [
      "2020-01-24",
      70
    ],
    [
      "2020-01-23",
      60
    ]
]
```

to this array:

```
    let dataTwo = [
  {
    date: "2020-01-28",
    price: 100
  }, {
    date: "2020-01-27",
    price: 80
  }, {
    date: "2020-01-24",
    price: 70
  }, {
    date: "2020-01-23",
    price: 60
  }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and destructuring seems to be the best way:

```js
let data = [
    [
      "2020-01-28",
      100
    ],
    [
      "2020-01-27",
      80
    ],
    [
      "2020-01-24",
      70
    ],
    [
      "2020-01-23",
      60
    ]
]

let result = data.map(([data, price]) => ({data,price}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Concise and clear! +1

Comment: very helpful! 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
let data = [
    [
      "2020-01-28",
      100
    ],
    [
      "2020-01-27",
      80
    ],
    [
      "2020-01-24",
      70
    ],
    [
      "2020-01-23",
      60
    ]
]

const result = data.map(item => ({ date: item[0], price: item[1] }));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data.map(([v1, v2]) => ({date: v1, price: v2}))
```